# Sequelize Access parent table's field on where clause

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have `Ad`, `Banner`, `Redirect` and `Script` models. `Ad` is the parent table.

**Ad model**

```
import UID  from '../util/uid';

export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Ad = sequelize.define('Ad',
    {
    uid: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(40),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(15),
      allowNull: false
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(15),
      allowNull: false
    }
  });
  Ad.hook('beforeValidate', (ad, options) => ad.uid = UID.generate());
  return Ad;
};
```

**Banner model**

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Banner = sequelize.define('Banner',
  {
      outcome: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(120),
        allowNull: false
      },
      image: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(120),
        allowNull: false
      }
  },
  {
    classMethods: {
      associate: (models) => {
        Banner.belongsTo(models.Ad);
        Banner.hasMany(models.Format);
      }
    }
  });
  return Banner;
};
```

So, I when I search a Banner I need to access to `Ad.uid` in order to retrieve all data: `https://myapp.doamin.com/ads/uid/dh49mmx02?type=banner`.

**Ad API**

```
router.get('/:uid', (request, response) => {
  const adType = request.query.type;
  let service = null;

  switch(adType) {
    case 'banner':
      service = bannerService; break;
    ...
  }
  service.findOne(request.params.uid, (ad) => {
    if(!ad) {
      response.json({eror: true, message: 'Ad not found'});
    } else {
      response.json(ad);
    }
  });
});
```

**Banner service**

```
export default class BannerService {

  find(qty, cb) {
    Banner.findAll({offset: qty, limit: 10})
      .then((banners) => cb(banners));
  }

  findOne(uid, cb) {
    Banner.find({where: {'Ad.uid': uid}, include: [Ad, Format]})
      .then((banner) => cb(banner));
  }
  ...
}
```

When I try to get a banner, this error is thrown: `Banner.Ad.uid column not exist`. I also tried with `$Ad.uid$` but it throws `An entry for table Ad is missing in from clause`.

Which is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i believe you should also specify the association from Ad to Banner by adding an `associate` function with `Ad.hasMany(models.Banner);`.

As for the query, Sequelize actually allows you to add a where statement inside your `include`

```
findOne(uid, cb) {
  Banner.find({include: [
    {model: Ad, where: {uid: uid}},
    Format
  ]}).then((banner) => cb(banner));
}
```